Recreating a bike seatpost in Fusion 360
I have to recreate the seatpost for a 3d printed water bottle holder but I can't seem to figure out how I should make it, this is the drawing from the manufacturer of the bike so this must be what they use to make it, everything is confusing. I'm not even sure if it's the top part or the one lower, the parts with yellow numbers is what I need


This is a small part of a technical drawing, we can't guess just by looking at this cropped image. this question probably fits better on https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/.

Hi. Welcome to GDSE,. CAD software is off topic here.  Try Engineering Stack Exchange, or 3D Printing Stack Exchange.
